# Using a saved report template and updating the Recordsource, then save to file

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to output reports.  They all follow the same information, just for different managers.  I can't seem to get any of the right syntax in to modify the necessary parts (Recordsource, Caption, and 1 field that will contain a set string).  I don't know what its asking me and I can get the code to find the next manager name (a recordsource) and cycle through them.  I can get the code to output to PDF file no problem.  It's the relevant code below that I need to figure out.  It's probably completely wrong. I haven't really dealt with reports yet.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptUsageReportTemplate", acViewReport
Reports("rptUsageReportTemplate").RecordSource = MngrUsgRptStr
Reports("rptUsageReportTemplate").Caption = MngrName & "'s " & Mnth & " Usage Report"
Reports("rptUsageReportTemplate").Controls("fldManagerHeader") = MngrName & "'s " & Mnth & " Usage Report"
Reports("rptUsageReportTemplate").Requery
DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptUsageReportTemplate", acSaveYes
```

The "docmd.openreport" Is in there because i couldn't stop getting the error 2451 - The report name [...] you entered is misspelled or refers to a report that isn't open or doesn't exist."  I know it exists and I know it's spelled correctly.  So it must be an open thing.  If I can get Access to output reports behind the scenes without needing to see the report open and close, that would be great.

In short what I want is for the Report I saved to be a template and just update the values a bunch of times and save it to file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a "Managers" Table or similar (tblManagersOrSuch) the following untested sub should get you going...

```
Sub DoManagersReport(Mnth As Integer)
   Dim rsManagers As DAO.Recordset
   Set rsManagers = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblManagersOrSuch")
   If Not rsManagers.EOF Then
      rsManagers.MoveFirst
      Do Until rsManagers.EOF
         DoCmd.OpenReport "rptUsageReportTemplate", acViewPreview, , , acHidden
         Reports("rptUsageReportTemplate").Caption = rsManagers!ManagerID & "'s " & Mnth & " Usage Report"
         Reports("rptUsageReportTemplate").Controls("fldManagerHeader") = rsManagers!ManagerID & "'s " & Mnth & " Usage Report"
         Reports("rptUsageReportTemplate").RecordSource = "Select * from MngrUsgRptStr Where ManagerID = " & rsManagers!ManagerID
         DoEvents
         Reports("rptUsageReportTemplate").Visible = True
         DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptUsageReportTemplate", acFormatPDF, "C:\" & rsManagers!ManagerID & " " & Mnth & " Usage Report.pdf"
         DoEvents
         DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptUsageReportTemplate"
      Loop
   End If
   'add error handling 

 End Sub
```

Note that setting the RecordSource forces a requery so you do not require that.
I would also suggest adding a fileSaveAs function to determine the save folder...